# Is it possible to make a raspberry pi look like a hue bulb to a hue hub

Tags: raspberry-pi, philips-hue

As the title says I'm looking to have my phillips hue hub recognize my raspberry pi as a hue light bulb.  From there I want to read the input to change some led light strips I have attached to it.

Comment: You'd probably be better off in https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com as they are more hardware oriented there. It looks like it uses Zigbee, so at the least you'd need a Zigbee adapter and a protocol description from Philips - good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to add a regular hue light and let the raspberry poll the hue hub about the state of that light. Use these values to change the ledstrip.  After that you don't have to use the original light bulb. The Hue app will mark it as unreachable, but it wil still update the state in the bridge.